# WPF equivalent of RootVisual in Caliburn.Micro docs

Tags: caliburn.micro

I am trying to work through the Caliburn.Micro Soup to Nuts tutorials using WPF rather than Silverlight.

In the "All About Actions" section of the Caliburn.Micro tutorial the following Silverlight code is shown in the overridden MefBootstrapper:

public class MefBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    //same as before

```
protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Application.RootVisual = new ShellView();
}

//same as before
```

} 
With the comment "In this scenario, we simply override OnStartup, instantiate the view ourselves and set it as the RootVisual (or call Show in the case of WPF)."

Does anyone know what is the format of the Show command that is used? (I have tried a number of internet researched items but none worked). I'm guessing it must be very simple because of the casual mention in the tutorial...

Comment: Are you using *Caliburn.Micro* version 2? Then you might want to take a look at my blog post [here](http://cureos.blogspot.se/2014/06/upgrading-caliburn-micro-from-15-to-20.html).

Comment: DisplayRootView<T>();